# Is there a simple way to solve a system of quadratic tensor equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a system of quadratic equations involving a known 3-D metric tensor $g_{ab}$ ,

$$g^{ef}X_{eab}X_{fcd}=g_{ac}g_{bd}-g_{ad}g_{bc}$$

$$g_{ab}=g_{ba}$$
Is there a simple way to solve for the third rank object $X_{abc}$ whose components are all unknowns?